# how to compress image programmatically

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, iphone

I am receiving images from xml feed they are very large in size how can i compress them before displaying them in table-cell.

my code is

```
   int blogEntryIndex1 = [indexPath indexAtPosition: [indexPath length] -1];
    imgstring=[[blogEntries objectAtIndex: blogEntryIndex1] objectForKey: @"image"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:imgstring];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
cell.imageView.image=[img autorelease];
```

please help me if you can.....

Comment: It would be better to compress them at source - by the time you've sent it to the phone, you've paid for the traffic.

Comment: Images are coming from Website through Rss Feed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got this utility method that will scale an image :

```
- (UIImage*)imageWithImage:(UIImage*)image scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)];
    UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return newImage;
}
```

Use it like this :

```
int blogEntryIndex1 = [indexPath indexAtPosition: [indexPath length] -1];
imgstring=[[blogEntries objectAtIndex: blogEntryIndex1] objectForKey: @"image"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:imgstring];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
UIImage *img = [self imageWithImage:[UIImage imageWithData:data] scaledToSize:CGSizeMake(20, 20)]; // Scale it to 20x20px
cell.imageView.image=[img autorelease];
```

NB I can't for the life of me remember where I got it from but it's served me well in the past

Comment: PLEASE TELL ME HOW TO CALL THIS FROM CELL METHOD

Comment: i am calling the above method like this....CGSize itemSize = CGSizeMake(20,40);
     ....[self imageWithImage:img scaledToSize:itemSize];

Comment: See my edit above - it doesn't change the existing image, it creates a new, smaller one.

Comment: But there is still the same problem of lazy image loading how should i get rid of this my application hang down when i scroll cells

Answer (score 0):

Simple to use:-

```
-(UIImage *)fireYourImageForCompression:(UIImage *)imgComing{

NSData *dataImgBefore   = [[NSData alloc] initWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation((imgComing), 1.0)];//.1 BEFORE COMPRESSION
int imageSizeBefore     = (int)dataImgBefore.length;


NSLog(@"SIZE OF IMAGE: %i ", imageSizeBefore);
NSLog(@"SIZE OF IMAGE in Kb: %i ", imageSizeBefore/1024);



NSData *dataCompressedImage = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imgComing, .1); //.1 is low quality
int sizeCompressedImage     = (int)dataCompressedImage.length;
NSLog(@"SIZE AFTER COMPRESSION  OF IMAGE: %i ", sizeCompressedImage);
NSLog(@"SIZE AFTER COMPRESSION OF IMAGE in Kb: %i ", sizeCompressedImage/1024); //AFTER

//now change your image from compressed data
imgComing = [UIImage imageWithData:dataCompressedImage];


return imgComing;}
```